# Keep a lion's head in class (6)

Tags: cryptic-clues

> Keep a lion's head in class (6)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is:

> CASTLE

Explanation:

> L(ion) in CASTE(class) with keep as def.

Complaints:

> A minor one. "A" doesn't do anything here. Could avoid using that.

Comment: I admit I wondered about that (your "complaint"), but thought it didn't sound enough like a sentence with "a" omitted